# Bash script to download image from URL

Tags: bash, web-scraping, wget

I'm looking for a bash script that will download an image from a site based on the following,

The web page has several images and each image named like `1234.jpg`, `4321.jpg`, `2345.jpg` and so on. When a user executes the script with the image name (i.e. `./some.sh 1234.jpg`) then the script should download the specified image file.

A part of my code will download an image from a website based on the date the it posted i.e user will execute the program along with date (./download.sh 01/02/1234) so the script will convert the give date and **scrape** the site.

```
function download_image() {
    htmlContent=$(content_storage $@)
    if [[ $htmlContent = "notFound" ]]; then
        echo -e "\nCannot connect to  site"
        exit 1
    else
        imageLink=$(get_image_link $htmlContent)
        if [[ $imageLink = "noImageFound" ]]; then
            echo -e "\nNo image was found for this date."
            exit 1
        else
            imageName=$(get_image_name_and_title $htmlContent)
            imageType=$(get_image_link $htmlContent | sed 's/.*\.//')
            echo -e "\nDownloading "\"${imageName}"."${imageType}\"
            wget -q $imageLink
        fi
    fi
}
```

This code is to download the image that was posted on the date that user provided. So, now if a user provides image name instead of data how to convert it.

Comment: Hi, I was asked to review your post by StackOverflow - typically questions posted here are of the sort where you're having a problem with an approach and want to get assistance - your query doesn't include any indication that you've made any attempt to solve your problem - you're only likely to get down votes to such a post...

Comment: This probably belongs on superuser since it's not about programming

Answer (score 0):

Look at wget or curl as options to perform the file download for you.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL